# Is this correct way to copy symlinked directory in bash?

Tags: bash, copy, symlink

I have directory `a` that is symlinked somewhere. I want to copy its contents to directory `b`. Doesn't the following simple solution break in some corner cases (e.g. hidden files, exotic characters in filenames, etc.)?

```
mkdir b
cp -rt b a/*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply adding a trailing '/' will follow the symlink and copy the contents rather than the link itself.

```
cp -a symlink/ dest
```

Bash globbing does not choke on special characters in filenames. This is the reason to use globbing, rather than parsing the output of a command such as `ls`. The following would also be fine.

```
shopt -s dotglob
mkdir -p dest
cp -a symlink/* dest/
```